# Loopback3 - Find current user by access token

Tags: express, loopbackjs

I have read in Loopback3 docs that getCurrentContext() has been deprecated. What I'd like to do is grab the access token and use that to find the associated user in the db, so I can get a company_id that the user belongs to and alter the query to include that in the where clause. I am using MySQL and a custom UserAccount model which extends from User.

I am new to Loopback so struggling to figure this out especially as most of the online help seems to point to getCurrentContext();.

I've set up some middleware to run on the parse phase:

**middleware.json**

```
"parse": {
    "./modifyrequest": {
      "enabled": true   
    }
  }
```

**modifyrequest.js**

```
var loopback = require('loopback');

module.exports = function(app) {
  return function tracker(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Middleware triggered on %s', req.url);
      console.log('-------------------------------------------------------------------');
    console.log(req.accessToken);
}
};
```

However req.accessToken is always undefined. I have added to server.js:

```
app.use(loopback.token());
```

Any ideas? Is this the wrong approach ?

**SOLUTION**

As per Kamal's comment below...

Try setting "loopback#token": {} in middleware.json under "initial:before"

This populates req.accessToken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, try setting `"loopback#token": {}` in `middleware.json` under `"initial:before"`.

Then, if you are accessing accessToken from request object, you can find the userId within that accessToken object. Try to log `req.accessToken`, you will find the userId therein.

You can use that user id to search for corresponding user in the database.

```
User.findById(req.accessToken.userId, function(err, user){
  if(err) {
    //handle error
  }
  else {
    //access user object here
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, however as stated req.accessToken is always undefined so there is no userId property. I am guessing there is some special thing to do in order for accessToken to exist ? Do you have an example of the middleware that works with your example ?

Comment: Try setting ```"loopback#token": {}``` in middleware.json under ```"initial:before"```.

Comment: Is there any documentation on this (l`loopback#token`)? This is exactly what I needed and it took me so long to find.

Comment: @OtisWright Here's [document](http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#loopback-token) of `loopback.token()`